# Paypal Onboard for sellers, strange behavior for generated sign-up link

Tags: paypal, single-sign-on, paypal-sandbox, marketplace

I know that it’s not the best place to ask this… I should ask this on Paypal forum, but they have way to complicated forum to post there …

I want to onboard Sellers. I’ve generated SignUp link, but when I go to this link, it just directs me to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ and that’s all
[, here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvJ4a.png)

What I expect is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HezyTwwgGlE

I followed this tutorial https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/seller-onboarding/